# Can't set reference in Excel IDE to MS Word

Tags: excel, vba, reference, ms-word

I want to populate a Word document with values from an Excel spreadsheet. Apparently the way to do this is to make reference to MS Word and use the following code snippet:

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
```

However I get an error:

> "User-Defined Type Not Defined"

So I try and set the reference via the tools menu but the references option is greyed out.

What do I need to do to enable this feature?

Comment: Maybe do late binding? Something like Dim WrdApp as Object   Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application"). If that doesn't work, try repairing office.

Comment: There are several possible reasons for the references option being greyed out. Make sure no code is running, and make sure you've selected the actual project (or an object within) in the Properties Window (the task pane to the left in the VBA editor).

Comment: @DanL - having code running appears to be the issue. I closed excel, went home and re-opened the file and I can now add the Microsoft Word reference. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references option in the editor is greyed out when the application is in break mode or code is otherwise running. I closed excel, reopened it and was able to add the Microsoft Word library reference.